Allocate free disk space to partition in dual boot (Fedora & Windows)
My setup is the following: dual-boot system with Fedora 40 (Linux) and Windows 10 operating systems.
I have several unollacted disk spaces when inspecting my hard drive in Fedora. The following picture should show you the partitions of the internal drive.

So, I am going to describe the partitions shown on the screenshot from left to right:

Partition 1 is the EFI-System
Partition 2 is reserved for Microsoft
Partition 5 is the Linux Data-System
Then follows 302MB of unallocated space
Partition 3 is the Microsoft Windows partition
Partition 6 and below is allocated to the Fedora System
Then follows 54GB of unallocated space
Partition 4 is the Microsoft Recovery-Environment
Then follows 1.1MB of unallocated space.

I would like to allocate points 4, 7, and 9 to either the Windows or the Linux (Fedora) partition. However, I am not sure how to do so in order not to delete or break any of the systems.
Any help is greatly appreciated!
